# Adding a UINavigationController to App

Tags: iphone

I built up a Navigation-Based app and I want to implement that functionality in another View-Based app I'm working on.

I figure I can just add a subview with a UINavigationContoller and add it to the superview but I cant figure out how to set up the UINavigationController from scratch.

Any ideas on how to basically add a navigation-based app as a subview that can be invoked upon a button tap?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really quite know the context, but you should probably use a Navigation Controller.

In your code you can something to the affect below:

```
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
// Do customisation here
[self.view addSubView:navController]
```

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but you could also consider using a UINavigationController in your App Delegate:

```
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
// Do customisation here
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[window addSubview:nav.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Fred, its correct, just one thing [self.view addSubView:navController] will be [self.view addSubView:navController.view]